# How to select the right line chart type in Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP3uf.png)
[image]
Hi, I'm experimenting with Excel macro at my internship and I have ran into an issue with Excel selecting the wrong line chart. When I record my macro I clicked on the line chart on the right and it created that, but when I ended the recording and went to run my code it's creating the line chart on the left. I want to know if there is something I need to change in my code for AddChart2 or add something that will make it create the line chart on the right. Thank you.

I looked online at AddChart2 and didn't see anything inside the parentheses that I could change to make it select the right chart.

```
Range("B45380").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("B45381").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("B45382").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("B45380:B45382").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B45380:B45704"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B45380:B45704").Select
    Range("B45380:B45704,K45380:L45704").Select
    Range("K45704").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'Channel-8_1'!$B$45380:$B$45704,'Channel8_1'!$K$45380:$L$45704")
```

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as a screencap. It may also be useful to see sample data

Comment: Did you notice that the data on those two chart options are presented differently?  I believe these charts are the same type (227), but they are just grouping your data in different ways when plotted.  Try recording your macro by first creating a blank chart, and then selecting the groups of data exactly as you'd like rather than as a bulk group.  This should take the "guess work" away from VBA.

Comment: The difference is **ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns** vs **ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows**.  
@Tyler

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone! I got it figured out.